# Visual Studio Code: "Unfortunately we have no symbol information for the file"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.0.0 and editing an html file (it's actually an *.asp file, but html is automatically selected as the language on the far right side of the status bar). When I position the cursor on, for example, a css class name and press Ctrl+Shift+O, the message "Unfortunately we have no symbol information for the file" appears. This is also true if I position the cursor on a javascript function name.

FWIW, my css files are included using "

What does it take for VSC to see the function definitions?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue with a Coffeescript file.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue (as I am working in CoffeeScript) so I dug into VSCode source code and I was able to find the code which is providing CS and Html Source Code.

Well, they *DO NOT* provide symbols - that's the reason why you can't see and navigate them - but just colorisation.

Therefore, it's not our problem, but lack of support on VSCode. You might want to be interested to file an issue eventually to their repo.

Hope it clarifies.